# How to read a stream with comma separated values in C++?

Tags: c++, csv, stream

I would like to emphasize on a fundamental question below:

Assume you have a CSV file and fill cells with Input Headers

The code should read this from .csv file and write the results into .csv file. It is nice to also code output total number of cases, plus average of cases. Here is a taken sample form SO and I would like to see how this can be efficiently adopted to complete this basic example.

```
   void create() 
{ 
    // file pointer 
    fstream fout; 

    // opens an existing csv file or creates a new file. 
    fout.open("reportcard.csv", ios::out | ios::app); 

    cout << "Enter the details of 5 students:"
        << " roll name maths phy chem bio"; 
    << endl; 

    int i, roll, phy, chem, math, bio; 
    string name; 

    // Read the input 
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 

        cin >> roll 
            >> name 
            >> math 
            >> phy 
            >> chem 
            >> bio; 

        // Insert the data to file 
        fout << roll << ", "
            << name << ", "
            << math << ", "
            << phy << ", "
            << chem << ", "
            << bio 
            << "\n"; 
    } 
}
```

Also, Read a particular record

```
void read_record() 
{ 

    // File pointer 
    fstream fin; 

    // Open an existing file 
    fin.open("reportcard.csv", ios::in); 

    // Get the roll number 
    // of which the data is required 
    int rollnum, roll2, count = 0; 
    cout << "Enter the roll number "
        << "of the student to display details: "; 
    cin >> rollnum; 

    // Read the Data from the file 
    // as String Vector 
    vector<string> row; 
    string line, word, temp; 

    while (fin >> temp) { 

        row.clear(); 

        // read an entire row and 
        // store it in a string variable 'line' 
        getline(fin, line); 

        // used for breaking words 
        stringstream s(line); 

        // read every column data of a row and 
        // store it in a string variable, 'word' 
        while (getline(s, word, ', ')) { 

            // add all the column data 
            // of a row to a vector 
            row.push_back(word); 
        } 

        // convert string to integer for comparision 
        roll2 = stoi(row[0]); 

        // Compare the roll number 
        if (roll2 == rollnum) { 

            // Print the found data 
            count = 1; 
            cout << "Details of Roll " << row[0] << " : \n"; 
            cout << "Name: " << row[1] << "\n"; 
            cout << "Maths: " << row[2] << "\n"; 
            cout << "Physics: " << row[3] << "\n"; 
            cout << "Chemistry: " << row[4] << "\n"; 
            cout << "Biology: " << row[5] << "\n"; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    if (count == 0) 
        cout << "Record not found\n"; 
} 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6VfZ.png
```

Comment: You forgot the [tag:c++] tag. This doesn't look very minimal (as in [mcve]) and it's also hard to understand what issues you have. The example data you mention above the code does not seem to have anything to do with the code. The code deals with moving averages etc.

Comment: Added tag C++. Also, added a statement that average, total of cases are also in wish list. I cannot start from scratch to create a minimal simply because there are many examples in SO and the issue is how to navigate to modify them for a most basic exercise for new users C++ - like the one I proposed at this question. Could you contribute to this initiative?

Comment: I'm afraid you are misunderstanding how this site is supposed to work. People will usually not do the implementation / adaption for you. Instead, try doing it yourself and if you get stuck, present a [mcve] with the one problem you need help with.

Comment: I am flexible to digest your rough comment and I do not agree partially for your comment on implementation/adaption. Anyway, I begun with even a simpler code. Hope you are OK with this.

Comment: Do you have simple comma separated data, or a fancy CSV format with quotes and commas inside quotes and that sort of thing?

Comment: No Ben. There is no much quotes inside. Basically, it is a filled Excel file for classroom which is saved as .CSV.

Comment: Ted, thanks for your effort, but I still think you made it too complicated. New users should also have a chance to ask basic question - maybe not a good question. On clarity side, let me know where are you struggling and what is your recommendation?

Comment: It's better now although it's not a [mcve]. I'll make an answer if noone beats me to it. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I added a read data section as well. Maybe it is not complete minimal reproducible example. But it wishes to receive your answer without beats :)

Comment: @Mohammad I got distracted but managed put something together eventually. I see that the question has evolved somewhat but I hope you can pick some pieces from my example anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mainly concentrated on adding overloads for `operator<<` and `operator>>` since you showed some interest in those earlier and describe what they are doing in comments in the code.

Since you are mixing input and output from streams that are comma separated and other streams I've added an adapter for `CSV` streaming as well as overloads for streaming to/from a user.

First, create a `class` to keep all data that belongs together in one data record. I've made it a simple `struct` here, which is a `class` with `public` access to its members per default.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// your student record
struct student {
    std::string name; // It's usually good to have larger types first so name goes first
    int roll;
    int math;
    int phy;
    int chem;
    int bio;
};

// read a student from an istream (like std::cin) - whitespace separated
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, student& s) {
    return is >> s.roll >> s.name >> s.math >> s.phy >> s.chem >> s.bio;
}

// write a student to an ostream (like std::cout)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const student& s) {
    return os << "Details of Roll " << s.roll << ":\n"
              << "Name: " << s.name << '\n'
              << "Maths: " << s.math << '\n'
              << "Physics: " << s.phy << '\n'
              << "Chemistry: " << s.chem << '\n'
              << "Biology: " << s.bio << '\n';
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// An adapter for comma separated streaming
struct CSVStudent {
    CSVStudent(student& s) : stud(s) {}
    CSVStudent(const CSVStudent&) = delete;

    // The CSVStudent holds a reference to a "student"
    student& stud;
};

// read a record from an istream - comma separated
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CSVStudent& csvstud) {
    std::string line;

    student& s = csvstud.stud; // an alias to the student to have to type less

    if(std::getline(is, line)) { // read a complete line
        // put the line in an istringstream for extraction:
        std::istringstream ss(line);

        char delim; // a dummy for reading commas

        // Extract the comma separated values. "delim" is not checked so it could be
        // any char breaking up the int:s.
        //
        // The below does things in the following order:
        // 1.  "ss >> s.roll >> delim"
        //     This extracts roll and a comma and returns
        //     a reference to ss, which is used in 2.
        // 2.  std::getline(ss, s.name, ',')
        //     Extracts a string until a comma is encountered.
        // 3.  Normal extraction for the rest of the int:s with the
        //     dummy variable "delim" where the commas are supposed to be.

        if(not(std::getline(ss >> s.roll >> delim, s.name, ',') >> s.math >> delim >>
               s.phy >> delim >> s.chem >> delim >> s.bio)) {
            // If we get here, the extraction from the istringstream failed, so set
            // the failstate on the istream too. Note the "not" on the line above.
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// write a record to an ostream - comma separated
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CSVStudent& csvstud) {
    const student& s = csvstud.stud;
    os << s.roll << ',' << s.name << ',' << s.math << ',' << s.phy << ',' << s.chem
       << ',' << s.bio << '\n';
    return os;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// get all students in the file as a std::vector<student>
std::vector<student> read_student_file(const std::string& filename) {
    std::vector<student> retval;
    std::ifstream fin(filename);
    if(fin) { // file opened successfully
        student stud;
        CSVStudent csvstud{stud}; // holds a reference to stud

        // loop for as long as student records can be read successfully
        while(fin >> csvstud)       // use the csv sdapter
            retval.push_back(stud); // and put the stud in the vector
    }
    return retval;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void create(const std::string& filename) {
    // open an existing csv file or creates a new file.
    std::ofstream fout(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    if(fout) {
        std::cout << "Enter the details of 5 students:"
                     " roll name maths phy chem bio\n";

        // Read the input
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            student stud;
            std::cout << (i + 1) << ": ";
            if(std::cin >> stud) {
                // Insert the data to file if one was entered successfully
                fout << CSVStudent(stud); // uses the adapters operator<<
            } else {
                std::cerr << "You failed to enter data for student " << (i + 1) << '\n';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    std::string filename = "reportcard.csv";

    std::vector<student> students = read_student_file(filename);

    std::cout << "There are " << students.size() << " students in the file.\n";
    if(not students.empty()) {
        // show the last record if there are any records in the file
        std::cout << "Record " << students.size() << " is:\n\n";
        std::cout << students.back() << '\n';
    }

    // create 5 new records
    create(filename);
}
```

If `reportcard.csv` contains this:

```
1,Ted,1,2,3,4
2,Foo,2,3,4,5
3,Bar,3,4,5,6
4,Baz,4,5,6,7
5,Bork,5,6,7,8
```

The program should start up like this:

```
There are 5 students in the file.
Record 5 is:

Details of Roll 5:
Name: Bork
Maths: 5
Physics: 6
Chemistry: 7
Biology: 8

Enter the details of 5 students: roll name maths phy chem bio
1: <and here is where you're supposed to enter the first of 5 new students>
```

Comment: A nicer way to do that is to have a simple wrapper class (CVSStudent) that simply holds a reference to a student but when serializer/deserialized reads/writes like a CVS file while a normal student streams in human readable form:  `std::cin >> CVSStudent{studentObject}; std::cout << CVSStudent{studentObject} << "\n";

Comment: @MartinYork Yes, I agree that adding a layer of adapters would make it a lot more versatile and would keep it cleaner. I might return to add that.

Comment: Thanks Ted, but, can you add a screenshot of .CSV and expected output for this code. The code is compiled successfully.

Comment: @Mohammad Sure, will return in a bit - I'm redoing the streaming part according to Martins idea.

Comment: @MartinYork Could you elaborate your comment a bit more. As a new user I have a difficulty to follow your suggestion. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @Mohammad It's good to have separation of concerns. By making the `student` simple and only capable of basic streaming to/from any `ostream/istream` it's easy to add support classes, adapters, that performs streaming in other specific ways, like `csv`  etc.

Comment: BTW, the current code accepts digits as NAMEs. How to define for names only accepts char and not numeric values?

Comment: Nice to have an option to update the .CVS file at current code, but what if we want to add an option to delete info from .CVS file?

Comment: @Mohammad You'll need to add validators where applicable and reject or accept values based on what you think is ok. To delete a value, you can simply delete it from the `std::vector<student>` and then write all the students in the vector to the file to overwrite what you had before.

Comment: Let say, you want to recall roll id and info of student to be printed what needs to be added in the code? Please see second part in OP question for clarification.

Comment: It can be done in any number of ways. If `roll`is supposed to be a unique number, you could make a `std::map<int, student> studentmap;` using `roll` as _key_ and `student` as _value_. To get a certain student using the `roll` could then be done with `student& stud = studentmap.at(roll);`  Or you can keep the `vector` and `std::find` students in it. Endless possibilities. :-)

Comment: Trying to understand your responses. Can you added into code and mark it so I can see where and how this can be implemented.

Comment: @Mohammad I think this answer is bulky enough as it is. It'll hardly help anyone else searching for help on a similar subject if it's cluttered with all to many solutions for other problems that isn't part of the original question. The questions asked should preferably be questions regarding specific problems so other people can also make use of them.

Comment: Right now you have a `std::vector<student>` with all the students that was read from the file. You can use [`std:.find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find students in that vector. If you have problems with that part, just make a short program with the `student` class where you demonstrate what you've tried and post a question about the problem you run into. That said, there are a lot of examples of how to use `std::find` on `std::vector`s here on SO.

Comment: I voted up your comments and I try to figure out for implementation. I do not think that I'll need to create a new question for this stuff.

Comment: @Mohammad Great! Hope it works out - and if it doesn't, SO is always open :-)

Comment: Sure Ted. I think that the Q&A and comments overall looks good around the OP's question?

Comment: TedLyngmo Should not we use standard namespace library instead of std:: - as a best practice?

Comment: Also I would say it is better to use float instead if int for objects of struct

Comment: I do not understand this line if (std::getline(ss >> s.roll >> delim, s.name, ',')) how did we define an unformatted input and with >>

Comment: @Mohammad The `ss >> s.roll >> delim` part is doing formatted input. It's calling `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, int&)` - and it's returning `ss` which is then used by `std::getline` to do unformatted input until `,` - and `std::getline` also returns `ss` wich is again used to do formatted input for the rest.

Comment: Get it @TedLyngmo - wonderful. Can you help me with link above! am stuck my question is closed. Folks have not had same level of your patience:)

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry, I can't even read what the picture says. I see it's some kind of math formula and there's a sum over something but ... Perhaps that part is best asked at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You got the point --it is sum over a vector function. We'd like to get a pseudo code for solving vector U in this equation but before that I would like to know how to initialize my problem in C++..can you vote to reopen my question there?

Comment: @Mohammad I won't vote to reopen when the question has a picture I can't even read, sorry. Try to transscribe it to text - but still, isn't [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) better for this? There are plenty of programmers there who will understand it from a programming perspective.

Comment: @Mohammad I think they expect the formula as text and to be in the actual question too. It won't be well received like that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo New Challenge: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60819407/13067762