# How to get base object's data in a new derived object?

Tags: c++, class, oop, derived-class

(Beginner in OOP.)
I have a `person` class which stores the name of the person. In a derived class instance `printer`, I need that name so that I can do further tasks with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Person{
  public:
  std::string name;
};

class Printer: public Person{
  public:
  void print(){
      printf("%s", this->name.c_str());  
  }
};
int main() {
    Person one;
    one.name = "john";
    Printer printer;
    printer.print();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I not doing to have `printer` see the data in `one` ? I'd be having several `printer`-like objects so storing "john" only once is the goal here.

Comment: Consider storing a reference to a `Person` in `Printer` instead of inheriting. A `Printer` is not a type of `Person`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo mind adding an answer ? after updating the question, it seems your answer would help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398540/creating-a-derived-class-object-with-existing-base-class-object this answer by `brado86` didn't go into details.

Comment: You can take a look at the [CSVStudent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729314/7582247) class in this answer that stores a reference to the object to be printed and that has a free `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const CSVStudent/);` function to do the printing. You'd need to make it a `friend` to your class if you make `name` private though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made the member vars `public` but this is not the right approach for the `OOP`, the right one is to have them under private access specifier and use setters and getters.

Now to your mistakes:

1. You use `void` for `main` but with c++ you can only use `int` for it.
2. You use `std::string` as an argument for `printf` but it can't accept it. (I passed the `c_string` of the `std::string` to correct that).
3. You use an object, from the parent class, and give it a name then use another object, from the driven one, to print the name of the first one. (I used only one)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person{
public:
    std::string name;
};

class Printer: public Person{
public:
    void print(){
        printf("%s",this-> name.c_str());
    }
};
int main() {
    Printer printer;
    printer.name = "name";
    printer.print();
}
```

After your comments, I have updated `Printer` class to do your inttent

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Person{
public:
    std::string name;
};

class Printer{
public:
    void print(const Person& person ){
        printf("%s", person.name.c_str());
    }
};
int main() {
    Person one;
    one.name = "name";
    Printer printer;
    printer.print(one);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes.. jdoodle  didn't complain about anything. \\ I want person name to be stored only once, & access it from several derived classes.

Comment: then you can create a class whose name is the same name of that person, make its member variable name constant and then inherit from it. or make the person a member var in the class printer without any inheritance.

Comment: *"make the person a member var in the class printer"*: uuh, no. `Printer` should  only print. `Person` should store only.